# Provider is not registered on the local machine in IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access, iis, oledb

When I execute my webservice via Visual Studio 2012, it works correctly ,but whenever my program executed by IIS I have an error like this.

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: The &#39;Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0&#39; provider is not registered on the local machine.
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
```

Additionally, I dont use OleDB Connection in my code ,I use Access DataSource so that my code doesnot include connection string.

How can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your target CPU is not X86, try setting it to X86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

ISS manager -> Click Application Pool -> Right Click Your Application -> Advance Settings -> Enable 32 bit Application set True